# Unable to git clone from Github Enterprise using a proxy

Tags: git, github, virtual-machine, git-clone, github-enterprise

I have a repository in Github Enterprise, I have worked with it in my machine and everything works fine, I'm able to clone, push, pull, etc...

Now I am trying to use this same repository in a virtual machine with Ubuntu installed that uses a proxy to connect to the internet. But when I try to clone I get the following message.

```
$ git clone https://cto-github.cisco.com/GDC-Interns-DevTeam/GDC-Dev-Back-End.git
Cloning into 'GDC-Dev-Back-End'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://cto-github.cisco.com/GDC-Interns-DevTeam/GDC-Dev-Back-End.git/': Received HTTP code 504 from proxy after CONNECT
```

I have configured the proxy in the file /etc/profile with the following lines

```
export http_proxy=http://my_user:my_pass@xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy/
export https_proxy=https://my_user:my_pass@xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy/
```

I have tested the proxy works by cloning from other repos and making some requests to public pages

```
wget https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
curl https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
```

Still I was getting the message so I tried to configure the proxy in git with the following commands

```
git config --global https.proxy https://my_user:my_pass@xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy/
git config --global http.proxy http://my_user:my_pass@xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy/
```

As last resort I tried to disable the proxy (because I thought that maybe it was an intern entreprise resource so it was conflicting with the proxy) but like this I wasn't able to resolve the host

```
$ git clone https://cto-github.cisco.com/GDC-Interns-DevTeam/GDC-Dev-Back-End.git
Cloning into 'GDC-Dev-Back-End'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://cto-github.cisco.com/GDC-Interns-DevTeam/GDC-Dev-Back-End.git/': Could not resolve host: cto-github.cisco.com
```

Finally I also noticed that the log message had a trailing slash (/) so I tried to put the name of the repository between quotation marks ("") but I wasn't able to remove the trailing slash from the log.

```
$ git clone "https://cto-github.cisco.com/GDC-Interns-DevTeam/GDC-Dev-Back-End.git"
Cloning into 'GDC-Dev-Back-End'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://cto-github.cisco.com/GDC-Interns-DevTeam/GDC-Dev-Back-End.git/': Received HTTP code 504 from proxy after CONNECT
```

Any thoughts on something else that I could try?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: This indicates imho that your proxy can't reach the github server.

Comment: @Clijsters I also think the same.. or that I can reach it but I'm unable to access the server with the proxy.. do you know of something else that I could try?

Comment: What you should try is the access from the proxy to the server. Where is the proxy? Are you able to ssh it or something? You can reach it, but the proxy can't. That's what the HTTP Error code suggests.

Comment: I would try to use the env variable GIT_TRACE_PACKET , it might show where the hangup is. Maybe not though but it is worth a shot